# css inspector Firefox where is the line number as firebug

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, inspector

I'm a web designer and I used to work with Firebug, I was very happy.

Now, in the Firefox Inspector why I do not have the line number of the css rule from css file? 
As you can see here, I have bootstrap.css but no line number: http://hpics.li/1de4f50

While the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS
says: "Filename and **line number**: on the right-hand side is a link to the rule. See link to CSS file"
I searched everywhere without finding...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find them in the `Inspector` tab, but in the same Developer tools interface if you:

1. Go to the `Debugger` tab
2. Find the file in question in the source list and select it.
3. On the left-hand side of the source panel you'll see the line numbers.